# opening a http session to a device and passing xml data to perform operation like get information from the device

Tags: php

our requirement is, to open a http session to a device(https://192.168.75.1/...) and passing xml data to perform operation like get information from the device

eg: Adding user to device

```
https://192.168.75.1/scgi-bin/platform-xml.cgi?sessionId=$sessionId&firstname="<DeviceConfiguration><userAdd><userName>nmanglik</userName><firstName>Nitin</firstName><lastName>Manglik</lastName><userType>3</userType><groupName>SSLVPN</groupName><password>cisco123</password><userTimeOut>10</userTimeOut></userAdd></DeviceConfiguration>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a call using the curl functions in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php They will allow you to do so from the server, and pass data, if you set appropriate options (the CURL library is quite large and complete).

Comment: is it possible to do same requirement by TCL Curl

Comment: what do you mean by tcl curl?